# fork() function will never return 0

Tags: c, linux

I am currently trying to run a fork function in C where in the child section of the code,
I am trying to execute a command using exacvp, but before the execution I am trying a printf function which never executes. I ran this in debug and I have noticed that the pid is never assigned 0. I did try a simple fork example on a separate project and it worked smoothly. Does anyone have an idea why the child section never executes?

```
int startProcesses(int background) {
int i = 0;

while(*(lineArray+i) != NULL) {
    int pid;
    int status;
    char *processName;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {

        printf("I am child");
        // Child Process
        processName = strtok(lineArray[i], " ");
        execvp(processName, lineArray[i]);
        i++;
        continue;

    } else if (!background) {

        // Parent Process
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        i++;
        if(WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
            printf(CANNOT_RUN_ERROR);
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        i++;
        continue;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your debugger is only attached to the parent process; `fork` returns 0 in the child process.

Comment: Please don't use the `C++` tag if you code plain `C`. It's not the same language, there's a huge diferrence!

Comment: OK so this explains why I couldn't see the pid = 0 on the debugger, however I still don't understand why the process would not split to the child process.

Comment: You can try a flush between the print and exec.  execvp() replaces the process and may not flush any pending output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stdio files are flushed on program's exit, but `execvp` directly replaces the process with another image, bypassing the flush-at-exit mechanism and leaving the `I am child` message in memory never to be sent to the screen. Add an explicit `fflush(stdout)` before `execvp`, or end your string with `\n` so that it is automatically flushed when running on a TTY.

Note that `execvp` never exits, and if it does, it is because it has failed to execute the new process. At that point, the **only** thing the child can do is to report an error and call `_exit(127)` (or similar exit status). If the child continues, an incorrectly configured command name will cause it to execute the rest of the parent's loop in parallel with the parent. This process will continue for other descendants, effectively creating a fork bomb that can grind your system to a halt.

Comment: I'm kinda lost here. How is this the accepted answer to the question? I don't think it serves as an explanation as to why pid=fork() never gets 0.

Comment: @JandroRojas The question and the answer are 7+ years old at this point, but I believe the issue was that `pid = fork()` **does** get 0, but the printing is lost. The first paragraph of the answer explains why the output was lost and how to fix the problem.